# Inotify read single event

Tags: linux-kernel, inotify

I have an app that registers multiple inotify watches on the same inotify fd. Due to the way the app is structured, I need events to be read one-by-one (instead of a single `read(2)` possibly returning multiple events), but so far I haven't found a way to do so.

Originally I tried to read the event head `struct inotify_event`, then read the rest of the event's data according to the `.len` field. But `read(2)` on an inotify fd shall fail with `EINVAL` if the supplied buffer is too small, as described in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html):

> ```
>  The behavior when the buffer given to read(2) is too small to return
>  information about the next event depends on the kernel version: in
>  kernels before 2.6.21, read(2) returns 0; since kernel 2.6.21,
>  read(2) fails with the error EINVAL.
> ```

Looking in the source, the implementation of `read` will try to return as many events as it can given the buffer size passed to it. As can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/notify/inotify/inotify_user.c#L242), given a successful copy of one event, it will continue the loop, trying to copy more events if present.

I also considered the possibility of using `ioctl(FIONREAD)`, but it returns the total size of all queued events, not just one (well, as expected...)

My best shot at it, currently, is to start with `read(..., sizeof(struct inotify_event))`. If that fails with `EINVAL`, try `read(..., sizeof(struct inotify_event) * 2 - 1)`, then with `sizeof(struct inotify_event) * 3 - 1` and so forth. That will be the least number of syscalls to achieve a read of a single event, without knowing its size beforehand. Obviously, though, it's not optimal.

Is there any better way to achieve a single read?

Comment: That sounds interesting.   I'm going to try it.  Any further comments?